# jQuery tr closest/next td

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table (please see this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkctb7kx/7/))

I want to add a `div` to a specific `td` where I only know the date, the name of the employee and the time.

I know the `id` of the date `td` (#18Dec2017), the name "Helen" and the time "09:00".

How do I find out the column and row of the red `td`

What I tried (you will find it in the fiddle):

```
var column = $("#18Dec2017").parent().next("tr").closest("td[title='Helen']").index();
var row = $("table td:contains('09:00')").index();
```

Comment: What was wrong with the thing you tried?  And don't say "it didn't work"

Comment: I cannot find out column and row :-) What I wrote is what I tried but it's obviously wrong

Answer (score 0):

`closest` is wrong, you want find. Cloest goes up the tree, you want to look for the child

```
var column = $("#18Dec2017").parent().next("tr").find("td[title='Helen']").index();
```

So what you need to do is find the cell and wrap its contents

```
var column = $("#18Dec2017").parent().next("tr").find("td[title='Helen']").index();
var cell = $("table tr:contains('09:00') td").eq(column)
cell.contents().wrapAll("<div/>")
```

Comment: Thanks! That only works when I have only once the name Helen. See the edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mkctb7kx/7/

Comment: What I try to find out is the td "underneath" the 18 Dec 2017 where the title is Helen

Comment: Thanks! Appreciated